# Windows search shows all files with searching file extension

Tags: windows-search

I need to search for file `wx.h` in in directory and all subdirectoryes. I just write filename in search box and press enter. On output I have many files with extension `.h`. Why? I was not asking for other files. How to ask windows to find exactly what I wont?

Answer (score 0):

By only putting in `.h` in your search it's going to give you any and all files with `.h` included. If your file is `wx.h`, then use that as your search term.

Comment: I put wx.h in search box and have many .h files in output with marked 'h'. Maybe it is searching in file content (I was not asking for that)